# Chrome Extension: Can I send multiple send messages from content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**TLDR**: I want data that was prepared in `content.js` to be available in `popup.js` so that when I click on it I can render it.

Upgrading @wOxxOm's solution he gave in my last question, after having data from `background.js`, I want to do some operations and want that info back to background.js so that prepared info should be able to send on `popup.js`. Code looks like below:

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log('Message got by Background')
    console.log(request)
    var msg_for_popup = ''
    if(request.from === 'content') {
        getInfo(request.msg).then(sendResponse);
    } else if(request.from === 'popup') {
        //want to send data prepared in content script to popup
        sendResponse('PREPARED DATA = '+msg_for_popup) //EMPTY here
    } else if(request.from === 'prepared') {
        msg_for_popup = request.msg
        console.log('Prepared in BG')
        console.log(msg_for_popup) //Data is here
    }
    
    return true; // keep the channel open for asynchronous sendResponse
});
```

**content.js**

```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:'content',msg:document.location.href}, res => {
  console.log(res);
  if (res.html) {
    var prepared = 'Prepared'
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:'prepared',msg:'Prepared'}, res => {                
    });
  }
});
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({from:'popup',msg:"send info"}, (response) => {
  console.log(response)
});
```

I was willing to avoid storage due to unreliability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the content script already receives the info from the background script you can save it as a Promise by omitting the callback from sendMessage so that the API auto-switches into the Promise mode:

```js
const dataPromise = chrome.runtime.sendMessage(url).then(data => {
  console.log('Received', data);
  return data.html;
});
```

Then popup.js gets the data from the content script directly via executeScript:

```js
(async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  const [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    func: () => dataPromise,
  }).catch(() => [{}]);
  document.body.append(`From content: ${result}`);
})();
```

Note that the data must be JSON-compatible i.e. string, number, boolean, null, or object/array that consists of these types. It can't be a non-trivial type like DOM element, class, function.

Comment: I will surely try but I have just updated my question, content script DOES send messages multiple times and it is being received as well, it is just when *POPUP* asks for info the variable is empty there

Comment: An instance of the content script runs in each matching tab so if you have 10 tabs there'll be 10 messages. Additionally, if you have `"all_frames": true` the content script will run in each iframe as well.